# how to get this correctly `echo "echo mukesh >> a.txt" >> b.txt`

Tags: windows, batch-file

i want text file b.txt to contain **echo mukesh >> a.txt**

I tried

```
    echo "echo mukesh >> a.txt" >> b.txt
```

but it puts text the " " as well and the below also doesn't seem to work

```
   echo echo mukesh >> a.txt >> b.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape any special characters that are not quoted. I put parentheses in to prevent trailing spaces.

```
 (echo echo mukesh ^>^> a.txt) >> b.txt
```